# React Relay (react-relay) with Typescript throwing TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, relayjs, react-relay

I'm running into an really bizarre TypeError with `react-relay` when trying to instantiate a class that extends `Relay.Mutation`. I've created a simple Typescript project with `create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts` to demonstrate the issue.

Whenever I run `yarn start`, this is what I'm seeing:

[image: Relay.Mutation instantiation error]

This error doesn't really make sense to me:
`TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined`

I'm just trying to instantiate a new instance of my own extended `Relay.Mutation` class. I'm really new to the React Relay world and ES6/Typescript in general so it's likely something silly I'm just missing.

In this simple project I'm using the example class directly as defined in the [DefinitelyTyped repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-relay/react-relay-tests.tsx).

Shouldn't I be able to use the class like so:

```
const atm = new AddTweetMutation({ text: 'asdf', userId: '1123' });
```

Here is what the  `AddTweetMutation.tsx` class looks like:

```
import * as Relay from 'react-relay';

interface Props {
  text: string;
  userId: string;
}

interface State {
}

export default class AddTweetMutation extends Relay.Mutation<Props, State> {

  public getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation{addTweet}`;
  }

  public getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
            fragment on AddTweetPayload {
                tweetEdge
                user
            }
        `;
  }

  public getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'RANGE_ADD',
      parentName: 'user',
      parentID: this.props.userId,
      connectionName: 'tweets',
      edgeName: 'tweetEdge',
      rangeBehaviors: {
        '': 'append',
      },
    }];
  }

  public getVariables() {
    return this.props;
  }
}
```

Here is the the entire `Hello.tsx` React component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import AddTweetMutation from '../mutations/AddTweetMutation';

export interface Props {
  name: string;
  enthusiasmLevel?: number;
}

class Hello extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  render() {

    const atm = new AddTweetMutation({ text: 'asdf', userId: '1123' });
    console.log(atm);

    const { name, enthusiasmLevel = 1 } = this.props;

    if (enthusiasmLevel <= 0) {
      throw new Error('You could be a little more enthusiastic. :D');
    }

    return (
      <div className="hello">
        <div className="greeting">
          Hello {name + getExclamationMarks(enthusiasmLevel)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Hello;

// helpers

function getExclamationMarks(numChars: number) {
  return Array(numChars + 1).join('!');
}
```

This is what my `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^20.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.19",
    "@types/react": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.2",
    "@types/react-relay": "^0.9.13",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-relay": "^1.1.0",
    "react-scripts-ts": "2.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
    "test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject"
  }
}
```

[Here's the project to github](https://github.com/justinlevi/HelloWorldTypescriptReactRelay)

Update: The typings are not currently valid for react-relay > 1.x. Please see the [thread on github for this issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/18676). I have also updated my repo with the workaround.

Comment: Check if `Relay.Mutation` actually exists. The version of the library and the typings doesn't match. Do a `console.log('relay.mutation', Relay.Mutation)` (or with `<any, any>`) to find out.

Comment: You're right. `Relay.Mutation` returns undefined. There doesn't seem to be a typings that matches the version of the library. What's the correct approach to fixing this? Why would Mutation no longer exist? Sorry, super new to Typescript and just trying to figure out a working strategy.

Comment: I'm assuming it has something to do with React v15.5 here: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-proptypes.html   ---   If I downgrade to : `"react-relay": "^0.9.*"` and `"@types/react-relay": "^0.9.13"` I can get past the error, but now I get a warning: lowPriorityWarning.js:40 Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated... I don't see an obvious solution for the latest versions???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `react-relay@1.1.0` has changed its API and `@types/react-relay@0.9.13` is outdated.

TypeScript statically analyze your code based on the typings (type definitions) available. So even thou `@types/react-relay@0.9.13` is outdated, TypeScript doesn't know and just act based on it.

To solve this problem, you can either:

- Contribute to `@types/react-relay` at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped to update its typings
- File issue on it at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped to see if someone can help updating the typings.
- Update the typings yourself locally using "module augmentation" (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)
- Not using `@types/react-relay` and do a `declare module "react-relay"` to mark it as `any` type (you will lose type safety and IDE support, but if the typings is not correct, it doesn't matter anyway).

For the last option, do this:

```
// custom-typings/react-relay.d.ts
declare module 'react-relay'

// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": [
    "custom-typings"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank. This is very helpful!